# Access violation when overwriting c string

Tags: c++, c

I'm a little perplexed why the following blows up:

```
char* c = "Hello World!";
*c = 'h';
```

When I allocate the string on the heap it works. So I'm just curious what wrong with my initial version.

Comment: On a modern C++ compiler this won’t even compile, or at the very least will issue a stern warning.

Comment: @KonradRudolph do you mean that this `char * c = "ccxcv"`; acts like a `char * const c;` ?

Comment: @Stephane No, as `char const*`, “warning: conversion from string literal to 'char *' is deprecated”.

Comment: Quote on the question used as original: "*This question gets asked about once a week on SO :), give me a minute to find the original and I'll link you to it.*". **Still relevant**

Comment: The [c-faq.com](http://c-faq.com/) website answers this question and more... which leads me to believe you either haven't bothered to research, or aren't very good at it. Please ensure you read the *entire site* as soon as possible, to answer any future questions you have *before* problems like this arise.

Comment: @KonradRudolph , it's clearer, thx.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`char* c = "Hello World!";` is a pointer to a string literal which is typically stored in a read-only memory segment. Attempting to modify it is undefined behaviour. Pointers to string literals such as this should more properly be defined as

```
const char *c = "Hello World!";
```

but the `const` is often omitted (in C, at least).

Comment: @Eric: good point - I've edited the answer now to make it a little more precise.

Answer (score 3):

```
char* c = "Hello World!";
```

Here `c` is a pointer which point to a literal string so you can not modify it

You can use this instead

```
char c[] = "Hello World!";
*c = 'h',
```

`c` here is an array of char and contains the chars of the string `"Hello World!"` so you can modify it.

Answer (score 3):

You're pointing `c` to a string literal, most likely stored in the read only memory segment, you can't change it. Even if you *can* physically change it, as per the C spec:

6.4.5 (String Literals)

> If the program attempts to modify [a string literal], the behavior is undefined.

If you allocate memory on the heap (or stack) and then copy the string to that location, you can change it as you see fit.

Answer (score 2):

Modifying string literals is [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). The main reason for that is that the compiler is permitted to place `"Hello World!"` in read-only memory.

On the other hand, the following is fine:

```
char c[] = "Hello World!";
*c = 'h';
```

Comment: It might be useful to explain to the questioner how it is that they have attempted to modify a string literal, rather than merely stating it is undefined behavior.

Answer (score -1):

Strings like `char * c = "Hello";` are string constants and are stored in read only data segment so you can't modify them [But some compilers do allow that]

Heap allocated strings are not in read only segments and are hence free to be modified.

Comment: I did not down vote but your answer is wrong. because a `char *p;` pointer could be pointed to a char array `char arr[30];`  Update uor answer otherwise there is risk to get more downvoted

Comment: Thanks @Mohamed . I hope the people who downvote would add the reason too

Comment: It's the first time I know that there is some compiler allow that could you please provide some references

Comment: Your capitalization suggests you're talking about ROM chips. Notice Paul R uses "read-only memory segment" which is different. It's all in RAM. Since modifying string literals is *undefined behavior* per the standard, compilers *aren't allowed* to allow it; at least, not in standards-compliance mode.

Comment: Actually I just wanted to say "read only area". Thanks, for pointing that out.